# Formatting a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql

I have a report and it must display text from a table, and I am not allowed to just type the text in the report or this would be really easy.

I just want to bold one word in a SQL string, and have it show up bolded in the SSRS report. Is there a way to format strings in SQL Server?

Comment: That type of text formatting should be done on the report side, not from the SQL side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can not. SQL Server stores and manipulates data, but is not meant to format it, let alone trying to apply some kind of visual formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the font for the strings in SQL Server. Any formatting <strike>must</strike> should be done in the Report.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in SQL Server (or rather, text types, like `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR`) are simply textual - they have no formatting and *can't* have formatting.

You will need to make the values bold in the report itself.